# Trying to select all text except for Twitter handle in Regex

Tags: regex, twitter, regex-lookarounds

I've exhausted everything I could find and just can't seem to get this to work. I have a .txt with rows of Twitter posts and I'm trying to delete everything but the @handles mentioned in the text.

For example:

Row1: This is the text of the tweet @Handle1

Row2: This text is meant for @Handle2 and @Handle3

*Would result in:*

Row1: @Handle1

Row2: @Handle2 @Handle3

I've come up with a regex expression to select the handles as: `@[^\W]*`

That works for all the handles in the set even if they have a colon or period immediately after them without a space (happens often).

I tried adding the negative lookahead command to it: `(?!(@[^\W]*))`

But I don't really know what else to add to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please add some example tweets where it is giving an incorrect result, and what result you want it to give

Comment: [`s.gsub(/(@\w+)|(?:(?!@\w+).)*/m, '\1 ').strip`](http://ideone.com/1P1j6G)

Answer (score 2):

So you can loop through each row, and scan for the twitter handles.

For example,

```
str = "This text is meant for @Handle2 and @Handle3"

str.scan(/@\w+/).to_a #=> ["@Handle2", "@Handle3"]
```

Then you can manipulate the array however you want.

the `\w` is any alphanumeric and underscore character, you can modify that if you need any other characters.